# Spring Data JPA query generation ignorecase to avoid column data to uppercase

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I'm using spring data jpa to fetch data using the ignoreCase property:

Employee class:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee {

@Id
private String id;


private String name;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Employee(String id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

Test case to get the stored value:

```
 @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
 @SpringBootTest
 @DataJpaTest
 public class EmapleApplicationTests {


@Autowired
private EntityManager entityManager;

@Autowired
private EmployeeRespository employeeRespository;


@Test
public void loadEmployeeData() {
    entityManager.persist(new Employee("ID1", "abab"));
    Employee e = employeeRespository.findByIdIgnoreCase("id1");
    assertEquals("abab", e.getName());

}

}
```

When i use findByIdIgnoreCase following query is getting generated:

```
select employee0_.id as id1_0_, employee0_.name as name2_0_ from employee employee0_ where upper(employee0_.id)=upper(?)
```

I don't want upper(employee0_.id) to convert to uppercase as I know the data is already in uppercase in the underlying database. I want only the upper(?) that is being passed to fetch the data to be converted upper case and I want to do this to improve performance. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Since you know the database field is uppercase, just do:

```
Employee e = employeeRespository.findById("id1".toUpperCase());
```

The performance **can** be significantly different; in our MySQL database with 100,000 email addresses, where that column is indexed, `findByAddress` takes 15 ms, but `findByAddressIgnoreCase` takes 400 ms.

Comment: indexed, but not for ignoreCase case :)

Answer (score 0):

You could write a native query or you write the jpa query by hand and you assume that the database value will always be upercase.
 Anyway it definetely is NOT a good pratice to "assume" the data will be in a certain way (uppercase) in the database, are you sure you are not overthinking the performance and making an issue out of it before it ever give any sign of being an issue?